# Exchange dates from c# webapi to java with gson

Tags: java, c#, json, asp.net-web-api, gson

I got a C# webapi project that returns objects of instance `foo`.

`foo` contains two DateTime properties in c#. I've configured my webapi to return always seven digits after the dot after the time. So, when the object got serialized into json, it looks like this:

```
{
  "Timestamp": "2017-02-11T11:49:00.0000000",
  "Changed": "2017-02-11T11:51:49.2620373"
}
```

Now, I try to deserialize the object with java. I chose `gson` for this.
I configure `gson` like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").create();
```

After deserialization, the two properties in java look like:

- Timestamp: `Sat Feb 11 11:49:00`, which is right
- Changed: `Sat Feb 11 12:35:29`, which is wrong

So my question is, it is possible to configure `gson` to work with the seven digits accuracy, or am i supposed to remove four of it?

Comment: Don't call `setDateFormat()`, and map to `LocalDateTime`, which can actually handle fractional seconds of more the 3 digits.

Comment: Andreas is right: `Date` can't hold ms fractions as well as `SimpleDateFormat` cannot, and what you're facing with is its lenient style: the overflown ms value is interpreted as seconds and upper. If you're free to use Java 8, then you should use `LocalDateTime` and implement a simple type adapter for it. If you cannot use Java 8 `LocalDateTime` for any reason, you might probably check another date/time libraries like Joda Time if they can parse ms fractions and round them to ms fractions in `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why you are getting that time:

`Date` in json : `2017-02-11T11:51:49.2620373`
Assuming 2620373 is milliseconds, it actually results into 2620 seconds which is 44 minutes.

Now, if you add 44 minutes into `11:51:49`, you get `12:35:29`. By default, `GSON`'s parsing is lenient, meaning it will add up the time/day and adjust the higher component (e.g. parsing `32/03/2017` as `Date` will result in `01/04/2017`).

If you want to ignore milliseconds then you can change the date format to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.` and it will result in correct Date, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.").create();
    Model model = gson.fromJson("{\"Timestamp\": \"2017-02-11T11:49:00.0000000\",\"Changed\": \"2017-02-11T11:51:49.2620373\"}", Model.class);
    System.out.println(model.getTimestamp());
    System.out.println(model.getChanged());
}

class Model{
    private Date Timestamp;
    private Date Changed;
    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return Timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        Timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public Date getChanged() {
        return Changed;
    }
    public void setChanged(Date changed) {
        Changed = changed;
    }
}
```